# How should my CAT6e cable be terminated?  No pairs?

Tags: networking, cable

I have just bought 60 meters of CAT6e cables, sold as "4 pair UTP RJ45".

I have looked at various videos on Youtube but I cannot determine the correct wiring. all the colors of the cable I saw there are different from mine. Mine is untwisted, and it is not color coded. I have 8 pin connectors all of a single color.

How should I wire this cable?

EDIT

THE PACKAGE DOES SAY TWISTED but they are not (twisted).

[image]

Comment: From your photo, that is not UTP cable, it may be suitable for voice telephone use but not for Ethernet. It wouldn't meet Cat-6 or even Cat-5 requirements - *"Each of the four pairs in a Cat 5 cable has differing precise number of twists per metre to minimize crosstalk between the pairs."*

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick thanks for your comment very helpful.will contact company.Doubt i will get money back.I have some cables like that and they seem to work on the cable it's written "verified TIA/EIA T68B B.2 CAT6".So all cable cat6 or catA are twisted .Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, all Cat5, Cat5E, Cat6, Cat6a are twisted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your cable isn't twisted, you have the wrong cable (either by accident or deliberate swindling).  CAT6 cables are composed of four twisted pairs by definition.  You specify UTP - that means 'unshielded twisted pair'.  It's supposed to look like this.

[image]

That's not to say that this stuff might not in theory do the job, but it's not up to spec so I'd just get my money back if I were you.  Also, if it's not color-coded, the only easy way to tell which wire is which is a continuity tester.  It doesn't really matter which strand is which, as long you're consistent - they're all the same copper.  (The default pinouts are chosen to reduce crosstalk, I believe, though, so they're not entirely arbitrary.)

Comment: thanks for your reply.I have uploaded a picture.the package does say utp twisted and their picture too see link http://www.etradehouse.com/Prd_Detail.aspx?prd_id=14769. As you can see from the picture I dont have white-green- etc...

Comment: Given the colors I have cannot work out the order from the diagram

Comment: @user231465 - That cable is not what that website says it's selling.  Hell, look at their own picture - it's not even close.  Call and complain and get your money back.

Comment: "doesn't really matter which strand is which" - not really. It doesn't matter which pair is which. But if for instance you swap brown with green, you must correspondingly swap white/brown with white/green. Each twisted pair must be connected to a matched +/- pair of signals.

Comment: @Shinrai thanks for answering.it's 3 hours looking on the net and your help is appreciated. My problem is cannot work out the order of the colors. All the diagrams I see on the net have white-green -brown-white . Mines are all single color + one looks beige.

Comment: @SteveFallows Just to eliminate doubts which color go in which connector given that there all single color . My take is  1)pale green 2)green 3) beige 4)blue 5)pale blue 6)orange 7) white 8) brown

Comment: @SteveFallows - Except they're not twisted pairs.  The problem is that this isn't even the right cable, which is what I've been trying to say all along.  ELECTRICALLY speaking, it doesn't matter (but in terms of data signals, crosstalk, etc, it does, which I said already)

Comment: +1: There's not even really a CAT6e, and all variations of CAT6 require the wire to be in twisted pairs. "Like most earlier twisted-pair cable, Category 6 cable contains four twisted wire pairs";  Installation: "The wire pairs _must not be untwisted_ and the outer jacket must not be stripped back more than 1/2 inch (1.27 cm)." [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable). There is also a TON of fake "CAT6e" cabling for sale out there. :)

Comment: @techie007 . I am confused!!!. So there is no cat6e.What about cat6a? Also I already have small cables virtually the same all made up and I have broken one connectors and they look the same.Are you saying that if when you cut the cable if not twisted is a fake?

Comment: @techie007 seen the link and that is exactly my point and confusion .My cable looks different inside.I guess i should buy it from a reputable place.Why do the other cables that I have got work then?

Comment: CAT6A exists.  You _sure_ you read that Wikipedia entry? :)  No need for confusion, you bought fake "CAT6E" cabling, and got some generic industrial cabling. I can tell by looking as the sheathing in your pic that it's CHEAP.  Also, there's no such thing as "RJ45" cabling either because [RJ45](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack#RJ45) is the jack, not the cable. ;)

Comment: Yes, you should *buy them from a reputable place*.  This isn't what you paid for.  Get your money back.  That's what I've been trying to say all along.

Comment: @user231465: The web-page you link to is contradictory, the graphic title says Cat-5e at the top but say Cat-6e (which doesn't exist) at the bottom. The text says "quality construction" but then says "copper clad aluminium" (aluminium is cheaper than copper). It says 26 [AWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge#Table_of_AWG_wire_sizes) but I believe Cat-6 requires 22 to 24 AWG copper (24 AWG is thicker than 26 AWG). I wouldn't trust that company.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware - CAT6e does not exist. They can make whatever cable they want and call it 6e, there's nothing you can do.
Should definitely be twisted, also looks like aluminium conductors which should be copper.
Probably not bad for short patches, but will be lossy and I wouldn't chance anything over 1m.